# How can I overlay a ProgressBar on top of a circular ImageView and have the ProgressBar match the dimensions exactly?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a UI with the following constraints:

- I must describe the layout in XML.
- I can only use common widgets like `FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `ImageView`, and even `ProgressBar`.
- I don't know the size of my container.

Here's what I want to happen:

- An ImageView with a circle inside it should maintain its aspect ratio and fill as much of the vertical + horizontal space as possible, centering inside of that. That ImageView will have an icon in the center of it with some padding around it from the circle background.
- A ProgressBar which rotates a ring should match the size of the ImageView, sharing its exterior border with the ImageView exactly. It should also be centered in the same container.

Here's what I've got so far, but it only works sometimes. Seems like it only works when the `adjustViewBounds` flag is actually changing the size of the view. I've also been able to tweak this to make it work in other cases, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make this work regardless of the conditions.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_blue"
            android:contentDescription="@string/icon_content_description"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/greenProgress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-6dp"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_green"
            android:indeterminateDuration="1600"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateOnly="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/yellowProgress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-6dp"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_yellow"
            android:indeterminateDuration="800"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateOnly="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try by changing progressbar's width & height to android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" and remove margins

Comment: set progress bar opacity to transparent and make center in vertical true

Comment: @user4551037 that didn't work. ended up making the progressbar much smaller. Tried doing similar and using layout_alignTop/bottom/start/end as well to no avail. Had the same effect as match_parent.

Comment: @GaneshPatil I don't understand why opacity would help here? And it's already centered both vertically and horizontally in my example, it's just not stretching to the bounds of the ImageView sibling.

Comment: Are you sure it's the progress bar's view that's the problem and not the drawable inside it? If I remember correctly, progress bars don't scale their drawables without some extra finagling. My first step would be set the background colors of both views to some (different) bright ugly colors (whichever view is laid out on top should have a half-transparent by color so you can see behind it). This would tell you if the view is stretching appropriately but the drawable isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the underlying issue was the `ring` shape, not the `ProgressBar`. I'll explain why, but first, the solution!

## The solution

I used a png of the ring png with the gradient where it went from white to transparent. I made sure the outer edge of that png aligned with the outer edge of the ring. Then, I could use `<rotate>` on the bitmap directly. See below:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:duration="800"
  android:fromDegrees="0"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:toDegrees="360" >

  <bitmap
    android:src="@drawable/spinner_white"
    android:tint="@color/spinnerYellow"
    />

</rotate>
```

This allowed me to describe the ProgressBar I wanted to render in terms of how its outer edge aligned with the outer edge of its container.

### Why wasn't this happening when I was using the `ring` shape?

To explain that, I'll have to reference the [Drawable resources documentation on Shapes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape). Take a look at two attributes there referencing a radius: `android:innerRadius` and `android:innerRadiusRatio`. The description for both of those begins with: "The radius for the inner part of the ring (the hole in the middle)..." And there you have it. There's no way to describe the `ring` shape by its outer radius, only by its inner radius.

One interesting tidbit, and why ProgressBars using `ring` shapes never fill the bounds of their containers, is the default value for `android:innerRadiusRatio` is 9. That means the inner radius, by default, is the ring's width divided by 9. It'll usually be pretty small relative to its container!

Answer (score 0):

What might work is only using match_parent on one of the height/width layout params of the ProgressBar, and using wrap_content for the other. (i.e. `android:layout_width="match_parent"` + `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. This **might** allow the ProgressBar to lay itself out in the same manner that `scaleType="centerInside"` draws its image (but I have not tested it).